# Summing and grouping values

Tags: c#, xml, linq, grouping

From my xml testreport I need to do a weighted sum of the defects, group the sums per project and for all dates. Finally I need some list I can display in graphs on a web-site. I’m stuck with the last bit to extract the lists.

I have attached the xml and codesnip of how far I got so far.

```
namespace LinqTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int WDCFact_1 = 5;
            int WDCFact_2 = 10;
            int WDCFact_3 = 20;

            XDocument test = XDocument.Load(@"..\..\Helpers\XMLFile1.xml");
            var selected = from p in test.Descendants("Sample")
                           group p by p.Element("Date").Value into gDate
                           from projects in
                               (from proj in gDate
                                group proj by proj.Element("Project").Value)
                           select new
                           {
                               Date = DateTime.Parse(gDate.Key),
                               proj = projects.Key,
                               WDC = projects.Sum(t => (t.Element("Severity3") == null || t.Element("Severity3").Value == "") ? 0 : (int)t.Element("Severity3") * WDCFact_3) +
                                     projects.Sum(t => (t.Element("Severity1") == null || t.Element("Severity1").Value == "") ? 0 : (int)t.Element("Severity1") * WDCFact_1) +
                                     projects.Sum(t => (t.Element("Severity2") == null || t.Element("Severity2").Value == "") ? 0 : (int)t.Element("Severity2") * WDCFact_2)
                           };

            var allprj = (from p in selected
                         select p.proj).Distinct().ToList();

            var prj = from p in selected.GroupBy(d => d.Date)
                      select new
                      {
                          _d = p.LastOrDefault()
                      };

            string mybreakpoint = "";
        }
    }
}
```

**Expected result:**

```
List<DateTime> Dates = {12-02-2014, 13-02-2014, 14-02-2014, 15-02-2014}
List<int> WDC_prj1 = {45, 150, 65, 85}
List<int> WDC_prj2 = {110, 110, 115, 260}
List<int> WDC_prj3 = {250, 0, 235, 245}
List<int> WDC_prj4 = {170, 60, 250, 240}
List<int> WDC_prj5 = {0, 205, 0, 15}
```

**XML input:**

```
<HistoricalData xmlns:xsi="http:www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Sample>
       <Date>12-02-2013 00:00</Date>    
       <Project>Prj1</Project>
       <Business_Line>BL1</Business_Line>    
       <Severity1>9</Severity1>
    </Sample>
    <Sample>
       <Date>12-02-2013 00:00</Date>    
       <Project>Prj2</Project>   
       <Business_Line>BL1</Business_Line>    
       <Severity1>8</Severity1>    
       <Severity2>1</Severity2>    
       <Severity3>3</Severity3>
    </Sample>
    <Sample>
       <Date>12-02-2013 00:00</Date>    
       <Project>Prj3</Project>    
       <Business_Line>BL1</Business_Line>    
       <Severity1>8</Severity1>    
       <Severity2>3</Severity2>    
       <Severity3>9</Severity3>
    </Sample>
    <Sample>
       <Date>12-02-2013 00:00</Date>    
       <Project>Prj4</Project>    
       <Business_Line>BL2</Business_Line>    
       <Severity1>2</Severity1>    
       <Severity2>0</Severity2>    
       <Severity3>8</Severity3>
    </Sample>
    <Sample>
       <Date>13-02-2013 00:00</Date>    
       <Project>Prj1</Project>    
       <Business_Line>BL1</Business_Line>    
       <Severity1>6</Severity1>    
       <Severity2>8</Severity2>    
       <Severity3>2</Severity3>
    </Sample>
    <Sample>
       <Date>13-02-2013 00:00</Date>    
       <Project>Prj2</Project>    
       <Business_Line>BL1</Business_Line>    
       <Severity1>8</Severity1>    
       <Severity2>3</Severity2>    
       <Severity3>2</Severity3>
    </Sample>
    <Sample>
      <Date>13-02-2013 00:00</Date>    
      <Project>Prj3</Project>    
      <Business_Line>BL1</Business_Line>
    </Sample>
    <Sample>
      <Date>13-02-2013 00:00</Date>    
      <Project>Prj4</Project>    
      <Business_Line>BL2</Business_Line>    
      <Severity1>0</Severity1>    
      <Severity2>6</Severity2>    
      <Severity3>0</Severity3>
    </Sample>
    <Sample>
      <Date>13-02-2013 00:00</Date>    
      <Project>Prj5</Project>    
      <Business_Line>BL1</Business_Line>    
      <Severity1>1</Severity1>    
      <Severity2>6</Severity2>    
      <Severity3>7</Severity3>
    </Sample>
    <Sample>
      <Date>14-02-2013 00:00</Date>    
      <Project>Prj1</Project>    
      <Business_Line>BL1</Business_Line>    
      <Severity1>3</Severity1>    
      <Severity2>1</Severity2>    
      <Severity3>2</Severity3>
    </Sample>
    <Sample>
      <Date>14-02-2013 00:00</Date>    
      <Project>Prj2</Project>    
      <Business_Line>BL1</Business_Line>    
      <Severity1>7</Severity1>    
      <Severity2>0</Severity2>    
      <Severity3>4</Severity3>
    </Sample>
    <Sample>
      <Date>14-02-2013 00:00</Date>    
      <Project>Prj3</Project>    
      <Business_Line>BL1</Business_Line>    
      <Severity1>7</Severity1>    
      <Severity2>4</Severity2>    
      <Severity3>8</Severity3>
    </Sample>
    <Sample>
      <Date>14-02-2013 00:00</Date>    
      <Project>Prj4</Project>    
      <Business_Line>BL2</Business_Line>    
      <Severity1>8</Severity1>    
      <Severity2>5</Severity2>    
      <Severity3>8</Severity3>
    </Sample>
    <Sample>
      <Date>15-02-2013 00:00</Date>    
      <Project>Prj1</Project>    
      <Business_Line>BL1</Business_Line>    
      <Severity1>1</Severity1>    
      <Severity2>4</Severity2>    
      <Severity3>2</Severity3>
    </Sample>
    <Sample>
      <Date>15-02-2013 00:00</Date>    
      <Project>Prj2</Project>    
      <Business_Line>BL1</Business_Line>    
      <Severity1>8</Severity1>    
      <Severity2>6</Severity2>    
      <Severity3>8</Severity3>
    </Sample>
    <Sample>
      <Date>15-02-2013 00:00</Date>    
      <Project>Prj3</Project>    
      <Business_Line>BL1</Business_Line>    
      <Severity1>1</Severity1>    
      <Severity2>8</Severity2>    
      <Severity3>8</Severity3>
    </Sample>
    <Sample>
      <Date>15-02-2013 00:00</Date>    
      <Project>Prj4</Project>    
      <Business_Line>BL2</Business_Line>    
      <Severity1>8</Severity1>    
      <Severity2>8</Severity2>    
      <Severity3>6</Severity3>
    </Sample>
    <Sample>
      <Date>15-02-2013 00:00</Date>    
      <Project>Prj5</Project>    
      <Business_Line>BL1</Business_Line>    
      <Severity1>3</Severity1>    
      <Severity2>0</Severity2>    
      <Severity3>0</Severity3>
    </Sample>
</HistoricalData>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would do the trick:

```
List<DateTime> Dates = selected.Select(each => each.Date).Distinct().ToList();
List<int> WDC_prj1 = selected
    .Where(sample => sample.proj == "Prj1")
    .Select(sample => sample.WDC).ToList();
List<int> WDC_prj2 = selected
    .Where(sample => sample.proj == "Prj2")
    .Select(sample => sample.WDC).ToList();
// etc.
```

Note that 2014 dates (which you gave as your expect result) don't actually exist in your sample (it's all 2013 in there), but I assume it was a typo and all you wanted was a list of distinct dates.

**EDIT:**

Okay, I just noticed that if a value for `PrjX` is skipped, you want a 0 instead.

My code would give you `WDC_prj5 = {205, 15}`, while you actually want `{0, 205, 0, 15}` (because no `Prj5` comes after the first four samples).

We can fullfill this requirement by iterating the samples in a loop and keeping track of which `Prjs` were missing. Then - every time we come across `Prj1` again - we substitute them with zeroes.

For example:

```
var values = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).ToDictionary(n => n, n => new List<int>());
bool firstIteration = true;
var visited = new BitArray(5, false);
foreach(var sample in selected)
{
    int number = Int32.Parse(sample.proj.Last().ToString());
    visited[number - 1] = true;
    if (number == 1 && !firstIteration)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            if (!visited[i])
                values[i + 1].Add(0);
        }
        visited.SetAll(false);
    }
    values[number].Add(sample.WDC);
    firstIteration = false;
}
```

And now just:

```
List<int> WDC_prj1 = values[1];
List<int> WDC_prj2 = values[2];
```

Etc.

Or, if you think LINQ is cool and performance considerations don't scare you, you could throw the `BitArray` away:

```
foreach(var sample in selected)
{
    int number = Int32.Parse(sample.proj.Last().ToString());
    if (number == 1)
    {
        // we just started a new cycle...
        int expectedNumberOfValues = values.Values.Max(list => list.Count);
        values = values.ToDictionary(
            kvp => kvp.Key,
            kvp => kvp.Value.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(0, expectedNumberOfValues - kvp.Value.Count)).ToList());
    }
    values[number].Add(sample.WDC);
}
```

Collecting the results remains the same:

```
List<int> WDC_prj1 = values[1];
List<int> WDC_prj2 = values[2];
```

PS.

On a side note, beware of `DateTime.Parse`.

It's culture sensitive and it can crash on another version of Windows.

For example on my computer it crashed trying to parse `13-02-2013 00:00` (and it parsed `12-02-2013` incorrectly as 2nd of December).

In this case you'd be better off using `DateTime.ParseExact(d, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` instead. Even if it's only supposed to work on your PC - I have no way of knowing - it's still a good habit to have.

Comment: It's magic :-) Comments on DateTime.Parse taken. Just wonder how I can extract the Dates into a similar list.

Comment: @ThomasB My code gives you the same exact list of dates that you presented as your desired output (apart from the 2013/2014 confusion). So if the outcome doesn't meet your expectations, I'd need to know in what way